# How do I insert multiple rows from a form with one column incrementating - sql server

Tags: sql-server, forms, insert

I am a real nube when it comes to SQL Server. Thanks in advance for your patience. I'm not sure where to start with this.  I found a similar post for MySQL but not SQL Server.

Using a single sql command, I need to populate an existing table (table:serialdb) with a range of serial numbers (field:serialno) that increases incrementally by 1.  Each range will always be accompanied by the same descriptive job data from the same form (fields:date, jobno, batch, modelno).

Looking for something like this:

```
[id]    [int, nn]   [varchar nn]    [varchar]   [varchar]   [varchar]

uniid  serialno  date          jobno    batch   modelno
------------------------------------------------------
  1    1001      2014 10 22    13872    RS95    5001 31 4
  2    1002      2014 10 22    13872    RS95    5001 31 4
  3    1003      2014 10 22    13872    RS95    5001 31 4
  4    1004      2014 10 22    13872    RS95    5001 31 4
  5    1005      2014 10 22    13872    RS95    5001 31 4
  6    1006      2014 10 22    13872    RS95    5001 31 4
```

The form looks something like this:

```
(date)- '2014-10-22'
(jobno)- '13872'
(batch)- 'RS95'
(modelno)- '5001-31-4'
(serialno_first)- '1001'
(serialno_last)- '1006'
```

OR I could create 1 record and then duplicate it x number of times (range)

Either way would work for me.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: If you want to automatically generate serial numbers, you should consider making that column an IDENTITY column.

Comment: You can group by records on date,jobno,batch,modelno ; then get max & min of serial no. then PIVOT it.

Comment: @AK47 a PIVOT table sound interesting. Can you give an example?

Comment: @shree.pat18  I cannot change the serialno column to ID because duplicates are allowed if the product gets remfg or repaired with same sn.  But your comment is now making rethink, I should make 2 separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Make a new identity column in the table to increment from your desired seed. (Please ask if your are not sure about this step)

Step 2 - Populate all other relevant data in other columns.

Step 3 - Write an SQL like this...

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1)
SELECT Col1 + '-' + Col2 FROM NewTable
```

Please let me know if your are not comfortable with the syntax or steps of SQL Server. I can create a working example for you.

Comment: yes thank you, some working code would be very helpful.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "increment from your desired seed".  I can tell you the expected serialno value that will be entered will be up to 7 digits (in the millions) and qty (range of numbers) could be as high as 500 at a time (my example only shows 6).  I hope this info is useful. :\

Comment: Is there a way to insert the incrementing serialno and add the other data in the same statement? How do I write something like this?

If RECORD does NOT exists with SERIALNO between FIRST & LAST, create them and

INSERT (MFGDATE,JOBNO,BATCH,MODELNO)
VALUES ('SOMEDATE','VARCHAR','VARCHAR','VARCHAR');
WHERE SERIALNO IS BETWEEN FIRST & LAST